# how to resize UIScrollview dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming

well i working with to zoom image with UIScrollview..my UIScrollview size is fix so whenever i make a zoom of a image then it goes cut..i wanna do that as i zoom the image the UIScrollview also increse height and width as per image zoom..
any suggetions will be appreciated......

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autoresize UIScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039012/autoresize-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 3):

This should work :-)

1. Make a UIImage
2. Make a UIImageView holding the image
3. Put the UIImageView into a UIScrollView
4. Set the contentSize of the UIScrollView to the size of the UIImage
5. Remember to return the UIimageView in `viewForZoomingInScrollView`

Put this into your .h file:

```
UIImageView *imageView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
```

And remember to synthesize and release `imageView`

Put this where you want to make your scroll view:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.jpg"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];
[scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Add the UIScrollView delegate method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood the question when adding the above solution. This should do it :-)

`kScrollViewAddSize` is a constant which defines the amount to add to the UIScrollView's size.

In your .h file you should add the following:

```
UIImageView *imageView;
UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Remember to synthesize and release them.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.jpg"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(kScrollViewAddSize / 2, kScrollViewAddSize / 2, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    int width = imageView.frame.size.width + kScrollViewAddSize;
    int height = imageView.frame.size.height + kScrollViewAddSize;
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - width) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - height) / 2, width, height)];
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:0.5];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    int width = imageView.frame.size.width + kScrollViewAddSize;
    int height = imageView.frame.size.height + kScrollViewAddSize;
    [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - width) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - height) / 2, imageView.frame.size.width + kScrollViewAddSize, imageView.frame.size.height + kScrollViewAddSize)];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

Add the parth in `viewDidLoad` where you want to create your UIScrollView and add the two delegate methods.

Comment: Hello SimonBS thanks for your reply but the thing you are saying is to avoid the image cut...i understand that after making UIScrollview frame same as self.view then the image cut problem will be solved.... but i want to make UIScrollview as per image size..

Comment: for e.g. suppose my image size is 70 * 70 then UIScrollview size should be little bit bigger like 80 * 80 but as i will try to zoom then image will be bigger..suppose at that time zoom image size is 120 * 120 then UIScrollview size should be 130 * 130...

Comment: Thanks SimonBS for your post it helps me a lot..i succeeded to autoreseize the scrollview...after now i am facing another problem that after zoom effect it goes to left top corner always so for another zoom effect i need to drag it from corner to center..and i want that the scrollview should stay on the last place from where i did zoom..Zoom in and zoom out effect is perfectly ok but after that it goes left top corner is main problem.

Comment: WHat if I want to add many images to UIScrollView and want to make images autoresize properly when changing orientation?